# Java: Implementing parallel hierarchy of trees and its nodes

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

In order to practice data structures I'm implementing my own library of Trees. I've begun with BST and in following I'm about to implement AVL Tree, Red-Black Tree and maybe more. AVL & RBT are BST trees as well, so some class hierarchy is rather obvious. The problem I came into is that all those trees have other types of Nodes - AvlNode has balance factor flag, RgbNode has color flag, BstNode doesn't need any additional info (despite of references to parent, children and value which all Nodes need). So I've a hierarchy of Nodes and a hierarchy of Trees. I could give some flag attribute to BstNode and use it in extending classes but it is surely not a good way to do it.

The problem is how to deal with the fact that for example Bst.findNode() will return BstNode but in Avl I need AvlNode despite the findNode() methods will be the same in both (apart of return type).

I need help with planning the hierarchies or if those parallel hierarchies (as a code smell) are in general a bad idea, I need a workaround because I have no clue how to do it in proper way.

BstTree Class:

```
public class BstTree<T extends Comparable> implements Iterable
{
    private BstNode<T> root;

    public void addValue(T value)
    {
        BstNode node = new BstNode(value);
        addNode(node);
    }

    public void addNode(BstNode<T> node)
    {
        ...
    }

    public boolean removeNode(T value)
    {
       ...
    }


    public BstNode findNode(T value)
    {
        ...
    }
    //other less significant methods
}
```

BstNode class:

```
public class BstNode<T extends Comparable>
{
    private static int lastId = 0;
    private int id;
    private T value;
    private BstNode parent = null;
    private BstNode leftChild = null;
    private BstNode rightChild = null;

    public BstNode(T value) {
        this.id = ++lastId;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean isGreaterThan(BstNode n)
    {
        //...
    }

    public boolean hasLeftChild()
    {
        //...
    }

    public boolean hasRightChild()
    {
        //...
    }

    public boolean hasParent()
    {
        //...
    }

    public boolean isLeaf()
    {
        //...
    }

    public boolean hasOnlyOneChild()
    {
        //...
    }

    public BstNode getOnlyChild(BstNode node)
    {
        ...
    }

    public boolean isLeftChildren()
    {
        ...
    }

    public BstNode getConsequentNode()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can guess that the separation of responsibilities above may not be perfect, if it's wrong then I might get some of the methods from Node to Tree class but this thing is not a big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public abstract class BstTree<T extends Comparable,N extends BstNode<T,N>> {
    private N root;
...

    public void addValue(T value)
    {
        N node = newNode(value);
        addNode(node);
    }

    public abstract N newNode(T value);

    public void addNode(N node)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class BstNode<T extends Comparable,N extends BstNode<T,N>>
{
    private T value;
    private N parent = null;
    private N leftChild = null;
    private N rightChild = null;

    public BstNode(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public N getOnlyChild(N node)
    {
        // ...
    }
...
}

public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable> extends BstTree<T,AVLNode<T>> {
    ...
    @Override
    public AVLNode<T> newNode(T value) {
        return new AVLNode<>(value);
    }
}

public class AVLNode<T extends Comparable> extends BstNode<T,AVLNode<T>> {
    ...

    public AVLNode(T value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public AVLNode<T> getOnlyChild(AVLNode<T> node) {
        return super.getOnlyChild(node);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Won't there be a problem while instantiating a BstTree? Like an infinite recursive:
    BstTree<Integer,BstNode<Integer,BstNode<...>>> tree = new BstTree<>(treeIteratorType);

Comment: @kampr BstTree is an abstract class

Comment: A thing is that BstTree shouldn't be abstract or should have an extending class with that exact behaviour

Comment: I've made a BstNode an abstract and done classes extending BstNode and BstTree (giving Bst tree behaviour) and it works perfectly fine now. Thank you very much!!